# Android emulator plugin doesn't find the android SDK

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

I'm trying to configure [android emulator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) for Jenkins and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why the plugin can't find the Android SDK.

First, after cloning the project Jenkins always output:

```
[android] No Android SDK found; let's install it automatically...  
[android] Going to install required Android SDK components...  
[android] Installing the 'platform-tool,tool' SDK component(s)...  
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk -u -a -t platform-tool,tool
```

After that, it fails because the plugin probably doesn't know how to answer the license agreement.

```
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-bcbbd656' [y/n]: 
Unknown response ''.
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-bcbbd656' [y/n]: 
Unknown response ''.
Max number of retries exceeded. Rejecting 'android-sdk-license-bcbbd656'
```

So I just replicate the command my self and installed all the stuff. The output remains the same, No Android SDK found. I tried to chown and chmod 755 the folder to be sure that Jenkins can access it and again it failed.

I checked in the Jenkins configuration that I can explicit tell Jenkins where the android SDK is but know it fails with another error:
I filled the field **Android SDK root** with **/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/** but it shows **Required tools not found (adb etc.)**.

This is my **ls -la** at **/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk**

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 11:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 15 20:20 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jenkins jenkins    6 May 16 12:36 .jenkins-install-info
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jenkins jenkins    0 Dec 20 20:00 .timestamp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jenkins jenkins 1158 Dec  6 16:50 SDK Readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 15 19:45 add-ons
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 09:02 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x 19 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 09:49 docs
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 11:12 platform-tools
drwxr-xr-x  8 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 10:43 platforms
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 11:12 temp
drwxr-xr-x  9 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 16 11:11 tools
```

and this is the **ls -la** at **/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools**

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins    4096 May 16 11:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 jenkins jenkins    4096 May 16 11:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins  467531 May 16 11:12 NOTICE.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 1226659 May 16 11:12 adb
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 May 16 11:12 api
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins  176550 May 16 11:12 fastboot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   16644 May 16 11:12 source.properties
```

which clearly shows that adb is there and running as the command above shows:

```
sudo -u jenkins ./adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
```

Any help with this problem will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that there is really a bug when trying to accept the license agreement as reported in this [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17997) and the plugin is also looking at the wrong place to find **adb** since SDK 22 did move it from the original place ([issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17816)).

Answer (score 1):

You can "fix" the missing adb issue by creating a symlink from platform-tools/adb to tools/ (or is it the other way around..)

Comment: Good tip but I think the guys have already fixed these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin has this open issue with sdk22, sdk22 moved aapt to ../build-tools/17.0.0 and this quietly causes the plugin to not find the sdk, and so to try and download a new one:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18015

The workaround in the issue description, adding a symlink, did work for me.
But, I also had to delete the avd files in .android/avd/ (that had been created with sdk21) so that they would be recreated with the new sdk.